Find $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^\infty \frac{1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}e^{-x/n}}{(x+1)^2} \, dx$
Find $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^\infty \frac{1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}e^{-x/n}}{(x+1)^2} \, dx$.
I have tried a couple methods. As a first method, it is tempting to bound the integrand above by an integrable function. Now, as $x \geq 0$, we note that $e^{-x/n} \leq 1$ and $\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}} \leq x$; thus,
$$\left| \frac{1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}e^{-x/n}}{(x+1)^2} \right| \leq \frac{1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}}{(x+1)^2} \leq \frac{1+x}{(x+1)^2} = \frac{1}{x+1} \tag{1}$$
which is not integrable on $[0, \infty)$.
As a second method, a variable substitution may be helpful and then I can find a dominating function. Before doing so, I will split the integrand into two parts and note that $\int_0^\infty 1/(x+1)^2=1$; hence, what remains is the second part $\int_0^\infty \frac{\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}e^{-x/n}}{(x+1)^2}$.  I let $u =x/n$ which means $n \, du = dx$ and $x =nu$. So I get
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\frac{nu}{\sqrt{n}}e^{-u}}{(nu+1)^2}n \, du = \int_0^\infty \frac{n^{3/2}ue^{-u}}{n^2u^2+2nu+1} \,du = \int_0^\infty \frac{ue^{-u}}{\sqrt{n}u^2+\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}} \, du   \tag{2}$$
Now, $ue^{-u}$ is integrable on $[0,\infty)$ and since $\sqrt{n}u^2+\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{n^{3/2}} \geq 0$, we must have
$$\left| \frac{ue^{-u}}{\sqrt{n}u^2+\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}} \right| \leq ue^{-u}    \tag{3}$$
Thus, by dominated convergence
$$\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^\infty \frac{1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}e^{-x/n}}{(x+1)^2} \, dx =\int_0^\infty \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}e^{-x/n}}{(x+1)^2} \, dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(x+1)^2} \, dx = 1 $$
Does this look okay? My primary concern is particularly with regard to the fact that I split the integral up into a sum of two integrals and then defined a sequence of functions that only represent the latter (messy) part of the integrand. So maybe there's some nit-picking to do there perhaps? It may be okay after all since if I would not have split the integral, the former part would grow linearly while the denominator would grow at least quadratically

In your problem is hard to find a single dominating function as the factors of your integrand decay at different scales. In this situations, one may have to split the integral so that the intervals of integration can be control by the different scales involved in the integrando.

Just for your curiosity. : there is an antidrivative and, asymptotivally the definite integral is $$1+\frac {\log (n)-\gamma -1 }{\sqrt n}+O\left(\frac{\log (n)}{n^{3/2}}\right)$$

@Svyatoslav. I repeated my calculations and did not find any $\frac {\log(n)} n$ term.

@Claude Leibovici thank you for catching! This is a typo; correcting. Cheers :)

Integrating by parts a couple of times and making the substitution $x=nt$,
$$I=1+\frac1{\sqrt n}\int_0^\infty \ln(1+nt),(2-t),e^{-t}dt$$
$$=1+\frac{\ln n}{\sqrt n}-\frac{e^{-\frac1n}}{\sqrt n}\left(\gamma+1-\frac\gamma n\right)-\frac{e^{-\frac1n}}{n\sqrt n}\int_0^1(\ln t-\ln n)\left(2+\frac{1-t}n\right)e^{-\frac tn}dt$$
$$=1+\frac{\ln n}{\sqrt n}-\frac{1+\gamma}{\sqrt n}+2\frac{\ln n}{n\sqrt n}+\frac{2+\gamma}{n\sqrt n}+O\Big(\frac{\ln n}{n^2\sqrt n}\Big)$$

This is not ok. $0\ge 0$, but $\frac{x}{0}\le x$ is false (meaningless, even). You have to work hard to make that kind of bound. The integrand is not dominated by $ue^{-u}$.
It suffices to show: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_0^\infty\frac{xe^{-x/n}}{(x+1)^2}\,dx=0$$ Put $t=x/n$ and then we want to show: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_0^\infty\frac{te^{-t}}{(t+1/n)^2}\,dt=0$$
What you did is almost good though. We just need to handle the issue at zero more carefully. On $[1,\infty)$, indeed $t+1/n>1$ for all $t,n$ so I can bound the integrand (in absolute value! It is good that everything is positive here) by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}te^{-t}$; $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_1^\infty te^{-t}\,dt=0$ obviously. Now to bound on $[0,1]$; $0<e^{-1}\le|e^{-t}|\le1$ is fairly irrelevant, so our focus is on bounding $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\frac{t}{(t+1/n)^2}$. The integral of this can be gained elementarily as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(\ln(n+1)-\frac{n}{n+1})$ which thankfully tends to zero as $n\to\infty$. Done! (and no dominated convergence needed).

This answer is awesome. Can you explain the $\ln(n+1) - \frac{n}{n+1}$ a bit more? I'm struggling to integrate the integrand on $[0,1]$ using usual methods (unless it's supposed to be incredibly messy)

@GrigorHakobyan Sure, no worries. For any positive $a$ we can calculate: $$\begin{align}\int_0^1\frac{t}{(t+a)^2},dx&=\int_0^1\frac{t+a-a}{(t+a)^2},dx\&=\int_0^1\frac{1}{t+a}-\frac{a}{(t+a)^2},dx\&=(\ln(t+a)+a(t+a)^{-1})\Big |_0^1\&=\ln\frac{1+a}{a}-1+\frac{a}{1+a}\&=\ln\frac{1+a}{a}-\frac{1}{1+a}\end{align}$$And then just plug in $a=1/n$.

Thank you so much!

Looking at this again now. When you did the $t$ substitution in your answer, why doesn't $(x+1)^2$ becomes $(nt+1)^2?$ Because $x=t/n \iff t=nx$. I can't quite understand how you obtained the $(t+1/n)^2$ in the denominator

@GrigorHakobyan You need to consider the whole form $\frac{x}{(1+x)^2},dx$. It equals, with $t=x/n$, $\frac{nt}{(1+tn)^2}\cdot n,dt$ and if you divide numerator and denominator by $n^2$ you get $\frac{t}{(t+1/n)^2},dt$

Ah, thank you again!

In this problem there are different scales at play ($\sqrt{n}$ and $n$). In these kinds of situations it is often useful to split the integral in intervals that grow as $n\rightarrow\infty$ and/or use the following version of dominated convergence:

If $|f_n|\leq g_n$, $\lim_nf_n=f$, $\lim_ng_n=g$ a.s.  and $\lim_n\int g_n=\int g$, then $$\lim_n\int f_n = \int f$$

In this particular problem, we may proceed as follows

For $0<x\leq n$
$$f_n(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\frac{xe^{-x/n}}{(x+1)^2}\leq e\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\frac{1}{x+1}=g_n(x)$$
and
$$\int^n_0 g_n(x)=e\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\log(n+1)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$$

For $x\geq n$
$$f_n(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\frac{xe^{-x/n}}{(x+1)^2}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}xe^{-x/n}=h_n(x)$$
and
$$\int^\infty_n h_n(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}(1+n)^2}\int^\infty_n xe^{-x/n}\,dx<\frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$$


Notice that
$|f_n|\leq g_n\mathbb{1}_{[0,n]}+h_n\mathbb{1}_{[n,\infty)}=\phi_n$, $\phi_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$ and $\int \phi_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$.
